# How do you call on an input for a simple "if" condition?

Tags: python

We just started learning Boolean stuff, and printing certain things if conditions were met. We made a statement (`x=5`) and a couple of `if` conditions for if it was greater than or less than, and a subsequent thing to print for it.

I want to do the same thing, but with an input, so I made this:

```
x = input("Input Value:")
    if x<1:
        print("yo momma")
    if x>1:
        print("my momma")
```

I get the error, "TypeError: 'int' object is not callable" in reference to the first line. What do I need to do to get this to work correctly?

Comment: `input` is probably shadowed by some code above.

Comment: ^^ what he said.  And then, when you have that fixed, you'll also need to convert the input to an integer in order to compare it.  The return value from input is a string.  So  x=int(input("Input Value:"))

Comment: Yup... Had other tabs in my editor, so it must have been calling on something from there. Once I closed the others, it ran fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In python functions are objects too, and live in the same namespace as any other variable. You very certainly have a variable named `input` somewhere before in your code that shadows the builtin function, example:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> input
<built-in function input>
>>> input = 42
>>> input
42
>>> input()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: Yeah, my spacing in there definately isn't right... I've never used this site before and am completely new to coding. I believe the spacing is right in my editor in python. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the you're using any version 3 (or greater) of python.

First, you need to properly ident your code, cause, python works with it.

In this case, try to apply this modifications to your code:

```
x = int(input("Input Value:"))
if x<1:
    print("yo momma")
elif x>1:
    print("my momma")
else: # equals
    print("yo")
```

You can convert the input using int cast to your desire type, and check the conditions with if-elif-else statement.

Comment: Appreciate it! Thanks!

Comment: you're welcome. Try to check the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/), or [hitchhiker's guide](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/). Surely, it will be useful.